# Convert all characters (except [0-9A-Za-z ]) to HTML Decimal Entities

Tags: python, html-entities, html-encode

I am new to Python but have been working with PHP for a while. I am looking for a method to convert all characters (except `[0-9A-Za-z ]`) to "HTML Decimal Entities". I have been searching around and haven't found a suitable method yet. I am looking for a carbon copy of [this PHP method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645675/convert-all-symbols-to-html-entities) in Python.

The closest methods I have found are these in Python, but they don't exclude `[0-9A-Za-z ]`: [Python3 Convert all characters to HTML Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609778/python3-convert-all-characters-to-html-entities) and [How can I escape *all* characters into their corresponding html entity names and numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494644/how-can-i-escape-all-characters-into-their-corresponding-html-entity-names-and)

Just like the PHP method, I want a function that can convert every character (current and future) excluding `[0-9A-Za-z ]` to "HTML Decimal Entities" and where the UTF-8 character encoding is assumed.

E.g. `"abcABC123 &%¤#"` would become `"abcABC123 &#38;&#37;&#164;&#35;"`

Comment: What exactly are "HTML Decimal Entities"? Did you just mean HTML Entities?

Comment: I mean the entity number. Take a look at this: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html 
e.g. an "&" becomes "&#38;" and a "#" becomes "&#35;".
So basically a string like, "abc123 &%¤#" would become "abc123 &#38;&#37;&#164;&#35;"

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this as an option on how to do it.

```py
import re

def html_entity_encode_all(string):
    return ''.join(['&#{0};'.format(ord(char)) if re.search("[^0-9A-Za-z ]", char) else char for char in string])

print(html_entity_encode_all('abcABC123 &%¤#'))
```

Output: `abcABC123 &#38;&#37;&#164;&#35;`

However, I don't know if there is a better way on how to do it or maybe a faster way to process it.